# What is the difference between VC++ project lib directories and linker inputs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am just approaching C++ development (from a C# background), and i am wondering what is the difference between Library Directories in C++ project settings (in Visual Studio):

[image]

and the Linker "Inputs" where i can also supply libraries:

Is there any fundamental difference between these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting got fumbled a bit in VS2010, it was much clearer in previous versions.  Where the settings you show in your screenshot were present in Tools + Options.  Which shows the core intent, they contain directories that are determined by the setup for Visual Studio and its components.  The locations of the CRT, MFC, ATL and SDK libraries.

The Linker + Input + Additional Dependencies setting is the important one, there you say exactly what .lib files the linker should link.  You can specify the path of a .lib file and be done.  But it is not uncommon that you only specify the name of the .lib file, then edit Additional Library Directories to tell the linker where to search for those .lib files.  Which is handy if the install location for, say, Boost isn't always the same or you want to switch from one version of Boost to another.

So in summary:

- Linker + Input + Additional Dependencies: add the .lib files you need to link
- Linker + General + Additional Library Directories: only use if you didn't specify the path of .libs
- VC++ directories: don't mess with it

---

Do note that the last two bullets only specify *directories*, not .lib files that the linker should link.  The first bullet specifies actual .lib files.  What is invariably confusing to starting MSVC programmers is that the linker magically knows how to find important .lib files without specifying them explicitly in the Additional Dependencies setting.

That's unfortunately the non-visual part of Visual C++.  There are two distinct ways in which a project can specify .lib files that the linker should link without using the setting.  The first one is the project template you selected to get the project started.  It uses *project property sheets*, files that specify default settings for a project.  You see them with View = Other Windows + Property Manager.  An important one is "Core Windows Libraries", it sets the Additional Dependencies setting to link the essential Windows .lib files, the ones you always need like kernel32.lib and user32.lib.  Those settings are "inherited" by your project.  Otherwise giving meaning to "NoInherit" if you ever run into it.

The second important way is the #pragma comment directive.  Which is used in source code, it injects a linker directive.  The "lib" variety is important, that tells the linker to link a .lib file.  In *addition* to what you explicitly specify in the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.  A very good example of that one is vc/atlmfc/include/afx.h.  Search for "#pragma comment".  Note the macro soup that selects the proper mfc .lib file, depending on compiler specific settings.  And the bunch of extra Windows .lib files an MFC needs to link.

The C++ build model is filled with a maze of twisty little passages.  The IDE tries to make you fall in the pit of success but in the process hides what's important to get to the next level of understanding.  It isn't different in C#, to know how to make the Reverse() extension method not consume O(n) storage requires digging in.

Comment: Libraries under VC++ Directories don't get linked into the output? What are they used for then ?

Comment: No, the setting only specifies *directories*, not libraries.  Directories that the linker will search for a .lib if it only has the file name and not the full path name of the .lib.  Look at the #pragma comment directive, used in the header files for many libraries to tell the linker that a certain .lib is required.  That's how the linker knows to link, for example, libcmt.lib to link the CRT.  You'll need to de-tune the C# thinking, it is far more involved in C++ because multiple tools are involved.

Comment: Added another section talking about .lib files.

Answer (score 0):

Most (not all) libraries come with two sets of files:

- Header files are #included in the source code that's using the libraries, to provide declarations for functions, classes, constants or whatever else might be needed
- Library files are binary code that contains the code of the library. These are used by the linker when it assembles the final executable